# Showing $A-\alpha Acc^T A$ is positive semi-definite

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, kalman-filter

I'm trying to show that for a positive semi-definite (PSD) matrix $A$, arbitrary vector $\bf{c}$, and positive scalar $r$, the matrix

\begin{align}
f(A)\triangleq A-\frac{1}{c^T A c + r}Acc^TA
\end{align}

is also PSD. I believe that this statement is true for 2 reasons. First, this is reminiscent of the filter step of the Kalman filter, where $A$ is the apriori error covariance matrix, and $f(A)$ is the aposteriori error covariance matrix, which should be PSD. Second, I evaluated this equations tens of millions of times numerically with random choices of all variables, and every time showed that $f(A)$ was indeed PSD.

Here are some of my attempts at the proof:

1. When $A$ is a scalar, we can multiply $f(A)$ by $c^TAc+r$ to obtain

\begin{align}
(c^TAc+r)f(A) &= c^2 A^2 + rA - c^2 A^2 \\
&= rA \\
&\geq 0.
\end{align}

2. When $A$ is a matrix, we need to show that $f(A)$ has only positive eigenvalues. So I tried finding a simultaneous diagonalization of $A$ and $\frac{1}{c^T A c + r}Acc^TA$ and failed because these 2 matrices do not commute.
3. I tried diagonalizing $A$ as $O^T D O$ so that I can write

\begin{align}
f(A) = O^T \left( D - \frac{1}{c^T A c + r} DOcc^T O^T D\right) O
\end{align}

but I got nowhere.

Any hints on writing down the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit the matrix on both sides by an arbitrary vector $v$:

\begin{align*}
v^T f(A) v &= \langle v, v\rangle - \frac{\langle c, v\rangle^2}{\langle c, c\rangle + r}\\
&= \frac{r\langle v,v\rangle + \langle v,v\rangle\langle c,c\rangle - \langle c,v\rangle^2}{\langle c, c\rangle + r}\\
&\geq \frac{r\langle v,v\rangle}{\langle c, c\rangle + r}\\
&\geq 0,
\end{align*}
where $\langle u,v\rangle = u^TAv$ is the inner product induced by $A$ and the key middle inequality is by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Wow! That was a neat trick.

Comment: Wouldn't $A$ need to be positive definite for this to work, not just semi?

Comment: @Hyperplane I think everything is fine as long as $r$ is strictly positive. Cauchy-Schwarz is usually stated in terms of norms but it also applies to semi-norms (see e.g. http://kaba.hilvi.org/homepage/blog/semi_norms.htm)